# Comparing Rails and JSON datetimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, datetime

I have a datetime in my database that looks like this:

```
2015-07-26T21:41:01.938 +03:00
```

I want to compare this datetime to the current time in my browser using Angular. I can call:

```
new Date();
```

which returns `Sun Aug 02 2015 16:33:50 GMT+0300 (EEST)`

but when I format it by calling `newDate().toJSON();`

I get `2015-08-02T13:34:41.134Z`, which allows the comparison but misses the three hours because my browser is EEST. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try comparing UTC dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error, browser doesn't missing anything. 16:33 in GMT+3 is 13:33 in UTC (GMT+0, or 'Z'). You can safely compare provided date-times, and be sure that time zones are handled properly.

More on ISO8601 date-time format (which is used in your example both for DB and client):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: That's a relief and yes, it seems that's right. Thanks for the answer!